# How can you enforce that a generic type is enclosed in a specific class?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, generic-programming

I came across an interesting problem recently: I want a method in a generics-class to accept only instances of an inner class of the specified generic type **only**. The goal, illustrated in the following example, is that a `CarInspector<CarBrand1>` can only inspect driving wheels manufactured by `CarBrand1`, while keeping `DrivingWheel` an inner class of `CarMaker`. Ther rationale being that I don’t want the `DrivingWheel` be defined outside an enclosing `CarMaker` subclass.

This was my first approach to the problem:

```
public abstract class CarMaker {
    public abstract class DrivingWheel {}
}
```

---

```
public class CarBrand1 extends CarMaker {
    public class DrivingWheelByCarBrand1 extends DrivingWheel {}

    private final DrivingWheelByCarBrand1 drivingWheel = new DrivingWheelByCarBrand1();

    public DrivingWheelByCarBrand1 getDrivingWheel() {
        return drivingWheel;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CarBrand2 extends CarMaker {
    private class DrivingWheelByCarBrand2 extends DrivingWheel {}

    private final DrivingWheelByCarBrand2 drivingWheel = new DrivingWheelByCarBrand2();

    public DrivingWheelByCarBrand2 getDrivingWheel() {
        return drivingWheel;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CarInspector<T extends CarMaker> {
    public void inspect(T.DrivingWheel arg) {}
}
```

---

However, the following code compiles just fine:

```
    CarBrand1 c1 = new CarBrand1();
    CarBrand2 c2 = new CarBrand2();

    CarInspector<CarBrand1> carInspector = new CarInspector<>();
    carInspector.inspect(c1.getDrivingWheel());
    carInspector.inspect(c2.getDrivingWheel());
```

Is there a way so that the compiler throws an error or warning in the line `carInspector.inspect(c2.getDrivingWheel())`?

**NOTE**: this question is besides the fact that the proposed design might not be the best choice and that defining `DrivingWheel` as `DrivingWheel<T extends CarMaker>` might be more sensible; it’s an interesting tangent nonetheless, and it’s a design alternative I’m considering for the specific domain I’m working at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use more generics.  Change the base `DrivingWheel` class to add a generic parameter that specifies the car brand:

```
public class CarInspector<T extends CarMaker> {
    public void inspect(DrivingWheel<T> arg) {}
}
```

Comment: You answered more or less at the same time I added the note below my question clarifying that point.

Comment: The only issue I have with this solution is that you’d need to define, in each `CarMaker`, something like:
    `private final DrivingWheel<CarBrand1> drivingWheel = new DrivingWheel<CarBrand1>() {};`

And then:
`public DrivingWheel<CarBrand1> getDrivingWheel() {
        return drivingWheel;
    }`.

I mean, there’s no way of enforcing that the `DrivingWheel` is of the generic type of the enclosing class.

Comment: It might be a very minor point, but you could declare `private final DrivingWheel<CarBrand2> drivingWheel = new DrivingWheel<CarBrand2>() {};` inside `CarBrand1`. I’d like a mechanism so that I wouldn’t need to take care of those details and I could have `DrivingWheel` be automatically genericized (if that’s a word) to the surrounding class. That’s the basic problem I wanted to solve in the first place (sorry if I was unclear by not mentioning it).

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been able to solve the issue by changing the class `CarInspector` to:

```
public class CarInspector<T extends CarMaker, U extends CarMaker.DrivingWheel> {
    public void inspect(U drivingWheel) {}
}
```

And then:

```
CarInspector<CarBrand1, DrivingWheelByCarBrand1> carInspector = new CarInspector<>();
```

Still, I don’t know if there’s a better way to do it...